# podspec with development dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

How can i specify a podspec dependency as local?

I have a main project with a pod file with a development dependency, pointing at a local folder. This is pod A.

Pod A has a podspec with it's own dependency graph. In the podspec there is a another dependency, which I control, Pod B, which I want to edit the source in development mode without the round trip to the server.

I've tried doing something like this, but it wasn't happy.

```
s.dependency 'PodB', :path => '../../PodBSource'
```

Comment: The podspec can't contain a path to the pod. What you can do is include the local pod B in your pod file so that when it goes to resolve the dependency it will use the pod that is already installed.

Comment: Cool, that worked. Thanks